# why does the textbox input control break out of a parent div?

Tags: css, html

i have the following html code

```
<div style="background-color:Red;width:100px;height:100px;padding:5px;">
    <input type="text" class="text" id="txtExtraSubject" style="width:450px;"/>
</div>
```

when its run in the browser, the div doesn't grow to accommodate the bigger textbox and it appears as the textbox is just breaking out the div.
Why is this happening and how to fix that?

Comment: please if you are downvoting comment on the reason of the down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `width: 100px` means "The width is 100 pixels" not "The width is at least 100 pixels".

You could apply a display property that makes it shrink wrap and add a `min-width` instead.

(untested: `display: table; min-width: 100px;`, other shirk wrapping methods are available, including floating the content (`float: left`))

Comment: well i am testing the min-width now , just want to make sure its compatable with ie6

Comment: IE6 doesn't support min-width. Google knows about hacks to fake it though.

Comment: well it works but the problem is that if i dont include display:table on the div it just grow to 100% width. the problem is i think display:table is not supported by ie7 so i am searching for another solution

Comment: `float: left` also shrink wraps

Comment: yeah it worked with flat:left :) with ie7 and ie6, thanks , please edit your answer using float and i will accept it :)

Comment: At this point, anyone requiring IE6 compatibility should be taken outside and beaten to death with Win3.x install floppies. Anyone refusing to upgrade from IE6 to anything else should get the same treatment, but using 15" crt monitors.

Comment: @Marc B: you shouldnt be telling me that , i am not using ie6 but not supporting users of ie6 means lost business so i have to, since i dont want to loose business. and actually having to support ie6 dont make me happy at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could also potentially use `overflow:auto;` on the parent.

It will constrain the text-edit to the parent div. But note that it will not increase the width of the parent as the width has already been specified. The result will be a horizontal scroll bar.

If this is not desired either decrease the width of the text-input or use `min-width` on the parent as opposed to `width`.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a height and a width for the div - why should it ignore what you're telling it to do?

Just remove the width or set it to 460px (450px for textarea and 10px for padding)

Comment: well i didnt want to set the width on the div each time i change the content , i want it to be like automatic and so min-width is actually what i need :)